# "Error in parsing the OpenID auth request" when realm and return URL start with HTTPS prefix

Tags: authentication, openid, google-openid, openid-provider

I'm trying to implement [Google OpenID](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) and use URLs starting with `https://` for both the realm and the return URL. When I pass:

```
openid.realm=http://mysite.com
openid.return_to=http://mysite.com/CompleteLogin
```

it works just fine, but when I pass

```
openid.realm=https://mysite.com
openid.return_to=https://mysite.com/CompleteLogin
```

navigating to the resulting URL redirects to `https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?lotsOfParamsHere` with the following text:

```
Error: invalid_request
Error in parsing the OpenID auth request.
```

I've looked carefully through the documentation - all the examples use URLs starting with `http://`.

Is using `https://` even supported for realm and return URL? How do I use them?